# How to infer a type from a component prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, components, react-props

I'd like `FormValueType` type to be inferred from `initialValue` prop. Seems to be easy and possible, but I can't figure out how to do that. If you can just turn me towards the right direction it can be also very helpful. I wonder if there's a concept (or some) I miss.

```js
export type AnyObject = {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  [k: string]: any; 
};


interface FormProps<FormValueType> {
  children?: ReactNode;
  initialValue: FormValueType;
  onChange: (_v: FormValueType) => void;
}
export const BasicForm = ({ children, initialValue }: FormProps<AnyObject>) => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState(initialValue);
  return <FormContext.Provider value={{ formState, setFormState }}>{children}</FormContext.Provider>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to tack on another [generic parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html):

```
export const BasicForm = <T extends AnyObject>({ children, initialValue }: FormProps<T>) => {
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXgnLW)

---

Addressing your comment; just add a comma:

```
export const BasicForm = <T,>(...) => ...;
```

Comment: I've got what confuses me: if I remove `extends AnyObject` just `<T>` is interpreted as a JSX tag. However `<T extends {}>` is interpreted as a ts type. It already resolves my problem, but, it's still interesting if one can have a generic type in JSX but without *extend*ing another type. Looks like this syntax is ambiguous. Can I somehow explicitly say to interpret `<T>` as a ts type in JSX? It's another question. Thanks for your answer. It helps a lot

Comment: @yevt Ah I had a hunch that was the case. See edited answer.